Why I am getting this error: "Each child should have a unique key prop"
Getting this error
"Each child should have a unique key prop"
My code is as follows
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Folder({ datas }) {
  const [toggleFolder, setToggleFolder] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>

      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleFolder(prev => !prev)}
        className='cursor-pointer'> {datas.folder}</div>
     
     
      <div
        key={datas.id}
        style={{ display: toggleFolder ? "block" : "none" }}
        className='pl-[20px]'
      >
        {
          datas.children && datas.children.length > 0 ?
            datas.children.map((key, index) => {
              return <Folder datas={key} />
            })
            : <p className='opacity-70'>empty</p>
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}


Because React requires mapped sibling elements to have unique React keys. You should ensure that datas.children array has unique values if you are using them as React keys.

import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Folder({ datas }) {
  const [toggleFolder, setToggleFolder] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => setToggleFolder(prev => !prev)}
        className='cursor-pointer'
      >
         {datas.folder}
      </div>

      <div
        key={datas.id}
        style={{ display: toggleFolder ? "block" : "none" }}
        className='pl-[20px]'
      >
        {datas.children && datas.children.length > 0 ? (
          datas.children.map(child => (
            <Folder key={child.id} datas={child} />
          ))
        ) : (
          <p className='opacity-70'>empty</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Even after it remains try adding an index
(
 datas.children.map(child,index) => (
    <Folder key={index} datas={child} />
))


You should add this key=index.
<Folder key={index} data={key}/>

